# Hangfire AutomaticRetry Attempts attribute not set on method

Tags: hangfire

I am using Hangfire v1.6.14.0.  I set the AutomaticRetry Attempts attribute on Method but the retry count is still the default 10.  Is there something else that needs to be done?

```
        [AutomaticRetry(Attempts = 3)]
        public void SubmitRequest()
        {
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure your task is being retried? Hangfire retries a task when it has failed (e.g., with an exception). However, if the process crashes, or is killed, or is terminated while running in the debugger, etc., it will run again when the process runs again, regardless of configured retry attempts.

Comment: Please also show how you register the task. There are some pitfalls there, according to comments on http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/dealing-with-exceptions.html

Comment: Are you putting the attribute on the main class and then calling the Interface (or vice versa)? The attribute needs to be on the specific interface or class that is called when queuing the job.

Comment: @playsted thanks for the tip. The only way I got it to work was to put the attributes on the interface. Not class!